# What do I name my files? How do I run a single test?

Tags: ava

In jest one names a file `thing.jest.ts`.  You can then run `jest thing.jest.ts` or point jest at a folder of test files eg `jest some_folder/sub_folder`.

**How do I do this with AVA?**

---

Things that don't work:

1. Can't use wildcards

```
$ ava /**/*.test.ts
✖ /**/*.test.ts does not exist.
```

2. Can't directly point to a file... maybe typescript doesn't work

```
$ ava ./src/Derivations/Sources/__tests/Source.test.ts
```

3. Can't run with ts-node

```
$ ts-node ./src/Derivations/Sources/__tests/Source.test.ts 
Test files must be run with the AVA CLI:
    $ ava src/Derivations/Sources/__tests/Source.test.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just requires some config.  By default though, AVA does not currently (Jan 2020) support Typescript files.

https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/typescript.md

> You can configure AVA to recognize TypeScript files. Then, with ts-node installed (`npm i ts-node --save-dev`), you can compile them on the fly.
>
> package.json:
>
> ```
> {
>     "ava": {
>         "compileEnhancements": false,
>         "extensions": [
>             "ts"
>         ],
>         "require": [
>             "ts-node/register"
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```